# find the unique record on two columns in oracle

Tags: unique, records

i have a table like

from              to                    distance
Bangalore       Hyderabad                1000
Hyderabad       Bangalore                 1000

here Hyderabad to Bangalore and Bangalore to Hyderabad both are having same distance.so i want
first record if the data comes like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just write a simple where clause which defines your need.

Eg: 
select distance from TABLE_NAME where ( ("from" = 'Bangalore' and "to" = 'Hyderabad') or ("from" = 'Hyderabad' and "to" ='Bangalore') ) and rownum <= 1

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0fc987/4

Comment: top1 is not working in oracle.could you please let me know how to get first row

Comment: this query is not giving any rows

Comment: FROM1  TO1 DISTANCE
Hyderabad Bangalore 1000
delhi mumbai 2000
mumbai pune 500
chennai delhi 3000
delhi chennai 3000
Bangalore Hyderabad 1000
...........................the data is like this.

Comment: when i am executing the upper query.i am getting the output as "no rows selected.

Comment: select * from table_name where(("from" = 'Bangalore' and "to" = 'Hyderabad') or ("from" = 'Hyderabad' and "to" ='Bangalore') ) and rownum <= 1

Comment: You're supposed to enter the actual table name instead of <table_name>. 

select * from <table_name> where ( (FROM1 = 'Bangalore' AND TO1 = 'Hyderabad') OR (FROM1 = 'Hyderabad' AND TO1 ='Bangalore') ) AND rownum <= 1

Comment: my query is this ...SQL> select * from uniq where((FROM1 = 'Bangalore' AND TO1 = 'Hyderabad') OR (FROM1 = 'Hyderabad' AN
D TO1 ='Bangalore') ) AND rownum <= 1;

no rows selected

Comment: my data is this...
SQL> select * from uniq;

FROM1      TO1          DISTANCE
---------- ---------- ----------
hyderabad  bangalore        1000
bangalore  hyderabad        1000
delhi      mumbai           1000
kolkatha   chennai          1000
chennai    kolkatha         1000